# Optimise page loading time faster on WordPress using Genesis child theme

Tags: performance, genesis-theme-framework

Does anyone knows how to optimize wordpress website that uses Genesis child theme to so it can load in less time and also I can optimize the javascript and CSS files for it.

Comment: Run it through Google Page Speeds and see what it recommends

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of ways to improve the speed of your WordPress site Irrespective of theme/ plugins you have used.

1. Add caching plugin supercache which will show tremendous decrease in the speed loading time of your site.
2. Put Following script in your sites .htacces file

   ```
   # BEGIN EXPIRES    
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
   ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
   ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year" 
   # END EXPIRES
   ```

this will help you to add browser caching to your site.

3. Minify all css / js files that you can.
4. compress/ resize images as per requirements of your sites.

I am pretty sure by applying above points you will definately improve the speed of your site tremendously.